# Validate | delimited txt file while reading from an array in perl

Tags: arrays, excel, perl

I have a text file with delimiter as | and it has some 10 columns. I have put this file in an array and before reading i want to put check for file being valid meaning non empty and file having fixed 10 columns. If number of columns < 10 then an error message should be displayed

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
my ($file, $fh);
$file = 'path/to/file.txt';
open $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
$line = <$fh>;
unless($fh=~/^.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*/){print "You have more than 10 columns!\n";}
if($10=~/\|/){print "more than 10 columns!\n";}
close $fh;
```

EDIT:
There's many ways and this is just a quick slop answer.  It will ensure at least 10 as stated, although you technically requested 9 or less with the > sign.

EDIT EDIT:
This will ensure at least 10, it could be more.  I'd recommend counting with global regex, but its been a while for me.  Alternatively, perhaps another method to ensure exactly 10:

```
$line = <$fh>;
my @check=split(/\|/, $line);
if (scalar @check !=10){print "bad file delimitation!\n";}
```

EDIT x3:
if($10=~/\|/){print "more than 10 columns!\n";} to ensure no more than 10, but try doing a global regex to count or the array method

Comment: Thanks. I am reading multiple files in an array and then further every file as an array. For example i have a text file like abc.txt with below data:          10|111|ab|12a|acc . Now there are times when this file is either blank or have some junk character. I want to handle all those scenarios

Comment: This will handle junk characters and ensures |  .  Feel free to change the statement following unless to suit your needs.  Alternatively, you can use if(-z $file){print "File size is zero/blank!";}

Comment: Also just wanted to know if passing multiple arrays (array of input files) in a function in perl is correct? Again i do not want to run into any issues because of missing error handling

Comment: If I read correctly, you want to pass multiple file handels into a function and process each there (to check them?).  Sounds like a great idea.  I'm on a phone right now, but you can pass an array into a function as checkfiles(\@file_array);  Then in the function: sub checkfiles{my @array=[@{$_[0]}];  foreach (@array){my $fh; open $fh, '<', 'file' or die $!; # do check } }

Comment: Where each element of the array is the path.  Then for the sub, have open $fh, '<', $_ or die $!  .  A few ways, to tackle it, this is just one.

Comment: Thanks again!! I am passing array as a reference using \@. In my subroutine  i am using it as a variable ($). For eg: @inputFiles="path of 5 files", resultData($finalFile,\@inputFiles); Here $finalFile being one consolidated output file. Inside subroutine resultData i say my($finalFile,$inputFiles)=@_. Now question is: am i doing right by treating array as a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can just count the number of pipe characters in each line. Ten columns means at least nine pipes, so you can say

```
perl -ne '($n = tr/|// + 1) and die "Only $n fields on line $.\n"' myfile.txt
```